# How can this loop be turned into idiomatic Rust?

Tags: loops, rust, iterator, idioms

Here is a working Rust function:

```rust
fn foo(src: &[u8]) -> Vec<u8> {
    let dst_len = (src.len() / 3) * 4;
    let mut dst = vec![0 as u8; dst_len];

    let mut si = 0;
    let mut di = 0;
    let n = (src.len() / 3) * 3;
    for _ in (0 .. n).step_by(3) {
        let v = bar(src[si], src[si+1], src[si+2]);
        dst[di+0] = baz(v, 0);
        dst[di+1] = baz(v, 1);
        dst[di+2] = baz(v, 2);
        dst[di+3] = baz(v, 3);
        si += 3;
        di += 4;
    }

    dst
}
```

It works but that loop doesn't seem like idiomatic Rust. It indexes into arrays using manually managed indices, pretty much like a `for` loop in C.

Is there a way to achieve the same result using Rust iterators? I think `chunked_exact` would work for iterating over `src`, but what about `dst`? What iterator could I `zip` with `src.chunked_exact` to write into `dst` in chunks?

Comment: What do you want to do with the reminder? Can you edit the question with that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is "idiomatic" can be a matter of opinion, but you can make use of more iterator methods, like `zip` and `chunks_exact_mut`:

```
fn foo(src: &[u8]) -> Vec<u8> {
    let dst_len = (src.len() / 3) * 4;
    let mut dst = vec![0 as u8; dst_len];
    for (s, d) in src.chunks_exact(3).zip(dst.chunks_exact_mut(4)) {
        let v = bar(s[0], s[1], s[2]);
        d[0] = baz(v, 0);
        d[1] = baz(v, 1);
        d[2] = baz(v, 2);
        d[3] = baz(v, 3);
    }
    dst
}
```

I used `chunks_exact` and `chunks_exact_mut` rather than `chunks` because it guarantees that the slice has the requested length, making them available separately if you need them. This seems to match your original code, which rounds off the length to an exact number of steps.

Comment: Thank you. I had `chunks_exact` and `zip` but couldn't achieve what I wanted with `chunks_exact_mut`. I've accepted your answer because it does do exactly what I asked for... but I see that I simplified my example too far. I do want to deal with remainders. `ChunksExactMut` does have an `into_remainder` method but I don't know how to use it: the iterator is moved when it is passed into `zip` and it doesn't have a `clone` method. How can I call `into_remainder` and use the iterator in the for loop?

Comment: On second thoughts, I suppose I want something like `last()` or `rev().next()` rather than `into_remainder()` for the destination vector - but the problem remains. Given that `ChunksExactMut` does not have a `clone` method, how do I call a method on it after using it in the for loop? Or do I have to create a new iterator?

Comment: You can use `chunks` instead of `chunks_exact`, but you will need to check the length of the slice in each case, to avoid going out of bounds. In my experience, using `into_remainder`  is usually tricky!

Comment: @c-- You can lend the iterator to the .zip - and then access it afterwards. Like  `let myiter = ... ; for ... in ... .zip(&mut myiter) { ... }   /* Now do something with myiter */`

Comment: @bluss thank you very much! That's what I was missing.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with that:

```
fn foo(src: &[u8]) -> Vec<u8> {
    src.chunks_exact(3)
        .map(|s| bar(s[0], s[1], s[2]))
        .flat_map(|v| (0..4).map(move |i| baz(v, i)))
        .collect()
}
```

Or if you prefer:

```
fn foo(src: &[u8]) -> Vec<u8> {
    src.chunks_exact(3)
        .map(|s| bar(s[0], s[1], s[2]))
        .flat_map(|v| vec![baz(v, 0), baz(v, 1), baz(v, 2), baz(v, 3)])
        .collect()
}
```

Not sure if you find one of them better.

Comment: Note that [looking at the assembly](https://rust.godbolt.org/z/ETCeSs), the first version *seems* to be better optimized, but someone good at interpreting the assembly could confirm, or not.

Comment: Thank you - this is great! Thanks also for the links to the Compiler Explorer. I didn't know that it supports Rust. Looking at the assembly, I can see that these versions are much less performant than the for loop ones: there's a lot of unnecessary memory allocation going on. It's a pity that the higher-level, functional-style code results in worse object code.

Comment: @c-- Unfortunately, the "zero cost abstraction" claim isn't always true. There is a lot of work remaining to optimize the iterators, but I don't know if the team is on this issue currently.